# Миграция переводит названия таблиц в нижний регистр

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework-core

Проект ASP.NET Core WebAPI, ORM `EF Core`, база данных `MySQL`, провайдер `Pomelo`.
Добавил Identity, создал миграцию и там с названиями всё в порядке:

```
migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
    name: "AspNetRoles",
    columns: table => new
    {
        Id = table.Column<string>(nullable: false),
        Name = table.Column<string>(maxLength: 256, nullable: true),
        NormalizedName = table.Column<string>(maxLength: 256, nullable: true),
        ConcurrencyStamp = table.Column<string>(nullable: true)
    },
    constraints: table =>
    {
        table.PrimaryKey("PK_AspNetRoles", x => x.Id);
    });
```

После применения миграции в БД все таблицы в нижнем регистре:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Не знаю распространяются ли настройки Json на миграцию, но на всякий случай конфиг из Startup:

```
services.AddMvcCore()
    .AddJsonFormatters(options => options.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver())
    .AddJsonOptions(options =>
    {
        options.SerializerSettings.Converters.Add(new StringEnumConverter());
        options.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;
        options.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();
        options.SerializerSettings.DefaultValueHandling = DefaultValueHandling.Include;
        options.SerializerSettings.NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore;
    })
```

Comment: Настройки json на миграцию не распространяются, есть отдельная секция для настроек БД (`services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
                options.UseSqlServer ...`, которую вы не привели. Навскидку - похоже на то, что в mysql установлено [lower_case_table_names](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/identifier-case-sensitivity.html) и EF к этому не имеет никакого отношения.

Comment: А можно ли тогда "заставить" ef core генерировать миграции с названиями таблиц в нижнем регистре?..

Comment: Конечно можно. Я знаю навскидку два универсальных способа: через [OnModelCreating](https://www.meziantou.net/entity-framework-core-naming-convention.htm) и через создание кастомной (было в EF6, вроде как в core обещали только к 3 версии) конвенции. Ну и руками вешать атрибут на каждую сущность никто не запрещал. Вы хотите свести ваш вопрос к этому?

Comment: Просто я не хочу лезть в настройки бд, чтобы не вспоминать потом при развёртывании, что я где менял. Ну и атрибуты я предпочитаю не использовать, только fluent api, да и доступа к сущностям identity у меня нет. Как запасной вариант - это перед применением миграции использовать какого-нибудь fixMigration.ps1 для замены имён таблиц на нижний регистр.

Comment: Я вам дал ссылку, там есть намёк на решение. Вот вам практически весь ответ на вопрос: `entityType.Relational().TableName = entityType.Relational().TableName.ToLower();`

Comment: Всё ок, можете добавить ответ - я отмечу как правильный.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для того чтобы не писать каждой сущности имя руками:

```
[Table("entity")]
public class Entity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Есть два варианта, один из которых (кастомные конвенции) ещё в EF Core не завезли и доступен только в EF6. Второй вариант - настройка в OnModelCreating:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

    foreach (var entityType in modelBuilder.Model.GetEntityTypes())
    {
        entityType.Relational().TableName = entityType.Relational().TableName.ToLower();
    }
```

Аналогично поступить и с остальными сущностями базы - индексы, внешние ключи.